# overloading unapply method in case classes: scala

Tags: scala

Consider the following piece of code:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
object User{
  def unapply(str: String) = Some(User(0, str))
}
```

Scala complains "error: cannot resolve overloaded unapply; case class User(id: Int, str: String)"
Is it not possible to overload unapply?

update: 
    unapply with larger tuple size.

```
case class User(id: Int, str: String)
object User{
  def unapply(s: String) = Some((User(0, s), s, 1234))
}
```

compiler still complains "cannot resolve overloaded unapply"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your unapply method could not be used in pattern matching

It works with

```
def unapply(arg: <type to match>) : Option[(<matched fields types>)]
```

(no tuple if only one field, boolean instead than Option if no field).

The standard unapply of User would be (The Scala Language Specification p. 67)

```
def unapply(u: User) = 
  if (u eq null) None 
  else Some((u.id, u.name))
```

It what you want is to match a user with a zero id as in

```
user match {case User(name) => ....}
```

that would be

```
def unapply(u: User): Option[String] = 
  if(u eq null || u.id != 0) None 
  else Some(u.name)
```

If you want that a string can match as a User (this would be rather bizarre)

```
def unapply(s: String): Option[User] = Some(User(0, s))
```

It would work with

```
"john" match case User(u) => ... // u is User(0, john)
```

I guess you want the former one. In which case both your apply and the standard one are two methods with the same argument list (one User parameter), so they are not compatible. This may be seen as a little unfortunate, as when methods are called as extractors, the distinguishing element is actually the size of the result tuple, not the type of the arguments.

Your method however, while not valid as an extractor, causes no conflict. I could not find something in the spec that would forbid it. Still, it is useless and a useful method would rightly not be allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! My bad.. I missed out the Some usage while typing in. I am actually looking for the later one(extract user out of a string) -- the above example may be a over simplification of the real scenario. You mentioned that the distinguishing element is actually size of tuple, I tried just for the sake of completion add in more tuple results, but the compiler does not budge. Any idea why?

Comment: You misunderstand me about the size of the tuple. I was regretting the syntax for extractor does not permit that. But I'm certain that it does not. On the other hand, if you want a String input, I do not understand why it is not permitted. What I would do is name the extractor something else. In the example at least, User is very misleading, I would prefer `object NameOfUser {def unapply(s: String): Option[User]...}`. I don't know whether it makes sense in your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will name the extractor something else. But still the compiler's message makes no sense. Atleast it should be clear about why I cannot overload apply and where is the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you can't override the unapply (especially) is most probably that it has the same signiture as the one that is automatically created by a case class's compantion object. Remembering that a function's signiture does not take into account its return value for the piurpose of overriding.