# Casting null to an instance of a case class in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, scala-2.11

I have a piece of code that relies on the existence of an arbitrary element of a certain case class in order to operate on the class's fields. There are [some](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator) [options](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) out there, and even though pretty much every Scala blog recommends not using `null` ever, it seems like not a terrible idea in type level programming (e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4443972/1650448). However, this code directly casting `null` to a particular case class does not work and does not throw an error, and I'm interested in why.

```scala
trait V {}
case class W(x: Int) extends V

val y = null.asInstanceOf[W]

y match {
  case w:W => println("null cast to W is a W")
  case _ => println("null cast to W is NOT a W")
}

// prints "null cast to W is NOT a W"

y match {
  case v:V => println("null cast to W is a V")
  case _ => println("null cast to W is NOT a V")
}

// prints "null cast to W is NOT a V"

val z = W(1)

z match {
  case w:W => println("instantiated W is a W")
  case _ =>  println("instantiated W is NOT a W")
  }

// prints "instantiated W is a W"

z match {
  case v:V =>  println("instantiated W is a V")
  case _ =>  println("instantiated W is NOT a V")
}

// prints "instantiated W is a V"
```

Comment: This is not type level programming and therefore the advice to avoid `null` stands. Use `Option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Type Patterns](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) are defined so:

> - A reference to a class `C`, `p.C`, or `T#C`. This type pattern matches any **non-null** instance of the given class.

So: `null` is a perfectly valid value of type `W`; but it won't be matched by the pattern `w: W`.

And the main reason why it isn't matched is precisely

> > I have a piece of code that relies on the existence of an arbitrary element of a certain case class in order to operate on the class's fields.

so when you match against `w: W` you want to know its fields and methods are available. But for `null` they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

Casting changes the compile-time type, not the runtime type. Pattern matching checks the runtime type. In fact, case class pattern matching even has an explicit check for null; see [Why is there a `null` check in the implementation of the `unapply` method for case classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56331580/2093695) (though that check doesn't affect your case since you're using a type pattern).

Also, even if it weren't for the pattern matching issue, you wouldn't be able to "operate on the class's fields" without getting a NullPointerException.